# /node_modules/react-medium-image-zoom/dist/index.js 29:45 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (29:45)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have installed `react-medium-image-zoom` on an react application, but once it is installed and inserted into the code, I get this error:

```
../node_modules/react-medium-image-zoom/dist/index.js 29:45
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (29:45)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| }
| 
> const testElType = (type, el) => type === el?.tagName?.toUpperCase?.();
| 
| const testDiv = el => testElType('DIV', el) || testElType('SPAN', el);
```

I have already searched through various topics, but none of them solve my problem.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "m2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "client:install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "client:build": "npm run build --prefix client",
    "db:migrate": "npx knex migrate:latest --knexfile ./db/knexfile.js",
    "db:migrate:down": "npx knex migrate:down --knexfile ./db/knexfile.js",
    "db:seed": "npx knex seed:run --knexfile ./db/knexfile.js",
    "db:latest": "npx knex migrate:up 20210719100845_create_user_table.js --knexfile ./db/knexfile.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.19",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "objection": "^2.2.15",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "php-express": "^0.0.3",
    "react-input-switch": "^2.2.2",
    "react-medium-image-zoom": "5.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mssql": "^7.1.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

and this is the code I put it in:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { COLORS, icons } from "utils";

import Zoom from 'react-medium-image-zoom'
import 'react-medium-image-zoom/dist/styles.css'

const StyledThumbnail = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 40%;
  max-width: 400px;
  > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
      font-size: 0;
      &.loading {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Thumbnail = ({ gallery }) => {

  if (!gallery || !gallery.length) return null;

  return (
    <StyledThumbnail>
      <div>
          <Zoom>
            <img src={gallery[activeImg].url} alt="" />
          </Zoom>
      </div>
    </StyledThumbnail>
  );
};

export default Thumbnail;
```

How can I solve it?
Thank you